# How to do get needed return vaule from multiple inheritence in java?

Tags: java

I am doing java puzzles to enhance my understanding about java but there two questions really confused me:

How can I get the needed return value from class B in that case? Thx.

Comment: Classes are much more readable when you don't try to put them all on one line. Also, please put a line of white space between classes.

Comment: You should know that each of these classes A, A1, and B, contain their own version of f. This variable hides the versions in each of their subclasses. However, I believe that when you use the superclasses' constructor via super(f), it uses the superclass' version of f.

Answer (score 0):

What do you meaning by needed value? As I understand it, you mean changing the value of the super class.
I hope this code will help you.

```
class A0 {

    int f;

    A0(int f) {
        this.f = f;
    }
}

class A1 extends A0 {

    int f = 0;

    A1(int f) {
        super(f);
        this.f=f;
    }
}

class B extends A1 {

    int f = 0;

    B(int f) {
        super(f);
        System.out.println(super.f);
        this.f=f;
    }

    int getFofA() {
        return f;
    }
}

public class question {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        B b0 = new B(5);
        System.out.println(b0.getFofA());
    }
}
```